# How to add JWT to authorization header?

Tags: php, authentication, http-headers, jwt

As described in the following slide, it is necessary that the client sends the `jwt` back to the server by an `Authorization Header` at the next request.

[image]

But how can I define the `Authorization Header` and add the JWT to the server?

My current status is:

1. User sends `username` and `password` to the server by a `POST` request.
2. The server creates the the `JWT`.
3. The server sends the signed `JWT` back to the client and saves it in a cookie.

Now my questions:

- **In case of a Login:**

  As I understand it, now its necessary to send the JWT back to the server. The server verifies the token and sends it back to finish the login process.

  How can I add the `JWT` to the `Authorization Header`?
- **In case of running a process and receiving data from a calculation:**

  Do I understand right, that the client has to send the `JWT` from the login to the server and a second `JWT` with the data; or can I send the data by `POST` request?

Comment: You authenticate with the API and if you've supplied valid credentials you get a JWT back. You send the JWT with future requests to stay authenticated. You can send data using POST as long as the JWT is in the header. How you do so depend on how you're making the request

Comment: As i understand you comment, the authentication process has finished with this moment where the JWT is stored in the cookie. And to stay authenticated,  I have to send the token with all future requests and verify them on the server and set them again. But how can i add the JWT in to the header? This is the step, I do not understand yet.

Comment: And as said, how you do that depends on how you make the requests :)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

So, You are pretty much correct with JWT. All you need to do when sending data from client to server (after JWT creation), is to add it to the request header. Many folks will try to keep along the same path as OAuth and add a Bearer token similar to the node snippet below:

```
var rp = require('request-promise');
options = {
  method: GET,
  uri: 'https://www.example.com/api/sample',
  headers: {
    Authorization: "Bearer <insert_your_JWT_here>"
  }
}
rp(options).then(function(res){
  <handle_response>
}
```

Granted I know you mentioned PHP, but the workflows are the same, its just the syntax is different.

Now, to verify that this token is present, the server would need to *verify()* that the token is valid with the secret that was defined. In every request made by the client, for an authorized endpoint, you would need to send this token everytime.

Comment: As is understand, your code snipped is from the server side? Is this right?

Comment: The snippet i showed is from the client. In my response, the server would be uri = _https://www.example.com/api/sample_

Comment: ok, so it is correct to say: i have to  create the process to  send the `authentication header` as a `Bearer` back to the server is to create on the client ( maybe with angularJS )  ?

Comment: sounds right....and depending on how your server interprets the token, it can be **Bearer** or whatever keyword you used. Any JS framework can modify request headers before send.

Comment: Make sure that if this is an ok answer, to mark as the answer; or feel free to ask if you are still confused.

Answer (score 5):

The user above was asking for a BROWSER-BASED means of settings authorization headers, or headers at ALL, for that matter.

(Node.js runs on the server. I realize that the accepted answer above refers to a SERVER authenticating to ANOTHER SERVER, and that the responder calling this "the client side code" is technically correct, with respect to server-to-server communication following the client-server model of who is requesting authorization with whom, but this does not address the true question: how does a browser modify it's authorization header to include a stored token etc.

Aside from the html href, which does not provide a means of accessing or altering headers sent, there are javascript means of sending requests.
One can use a standard XHR to demonstrate how one sets the headers via javascript

```
xhr.open('GET', url, true);
xhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + yourtoken);
xhr.send();
```

Note: There should be a space after the `Bearer` keyword.

You may be able to find php-templated means of inscribing the token into the rendered page (hidden element?) but javascript running in the browser provides the means for manipulating the request headers.
It's worth noting that cookies are automatically sent on all requests for a given domain, while local/session storage requires manually setting them usually.