# How to set authorization header (JWT)

Tags: python, django, request, jwt, request-headers

I am working on JWT authorization and I'm not able to figure out how to send the JWT as a request header for every request, so that I can use it to check if the user is authorized.

Right now, I am generating the JWT immediately after login, and setting it as a cookie. I want to use header instead of cookie.  How can I achieve this?

I am using django 1.6, if it is relevant information.

Comment: Hi, I'm not sure if I understand what you need. Do you want your Django project to read a JWT from a request header, or do you actually need to make a request to another API sending a JWT through the request header?

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on your request library. Could you tell me what library you're using to make requests? BUT: most request libraries out there should let you set the header of the request to include a JWT. Therefore, when the server receives the request, the server will "know" you are authorized because the JWT is in the header.

Take a look at [How to add JWT to authorization header?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41471563/how-to-add-jwt-to-authorization-header) as an example!

As for this:
`Right now, I am generating the JWT immediately after login, and setting it as a cookie. I want to use header instead of cookie. How can I achieve this?`

It's totally fine to set your JWT as a cookie. What you must do for every request is to get the JWT from the cookie. Look at: https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp for more details!