# Get JWT Token from header and verify it in PHP

Tags: php

I'm using JWT to authenticate users who can call my Rest API. However, right now I'm simply sending the JWT token with a POST-method

```
<form class="" action="../api/add_object.php" method="post">
        <input type="text" name="topic" value="" placeholder="topic">
        <br>
        ...
        <br>
        <input type="text" name="jwt" placeholder="jwt"> <!--JWT being sent here-->
        <br>
        <button type="submit">Submit</button>
 </form>
```

And I'm using it in following way (**validate_token.php**)

```
if (isset($_POST['jwt'])) {
    $jwt = $_POST['jwt'];
} else {
    $jwt = "";
}

// if jwt is not empty
if($jwt){

    // if decode succeed, set variable to true
    try {
        // decode jwt
        $decoded = JWT::decode($jwt, $key, array('HS256'));

        http_response_code(200);    
        $validate_check = TRUE;

    }
```

However, the problem is that this appears to be very unhandy because I'm often sending JSONs and I would have to mix these JSONs with a simple POST. I don't want the JWT to be added to the JSON since I would need to decode it first in order to get to the JWT.

---

My question is: **is there any way I could send the token via header and if so, how would I be able to get and verify it? Or if there is any other more simple way.**

Comment: i assume you use JS or something on the front end?

Comment: This has been answered here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41471563/how-to-add-jwt-to-authorization-header