# Fetching data and store it in the cache with flutter

Tags: node.js, mongodb, flutter, cookies, jwt

I am bulding an app with flutter. I am at the point of retriving data during the login process. The idea is to store this data in the cache and use it later for other operations. I am using nodejs with mongodb as backend and flutter as frontend. I want to retrive a list of specialization during the login process. Once the user is logged in the token is created and informations like userId, email and token are stored in the cookie. I have then a middleware verifyAccessToken that checks if the token is available from the cookie, if the check is ok than the api getSpecialization returns the list of specializations available. The problem i am facing is that i am including in the login APIservice in flutter the getSpecialization but i am not able to retrive the list since the verifyAccessToken middleware gets bypassed resulting in a 403 error. Any help would be much appreciated. Below is my backend and frontend code:

Nodejs
Login:

```
const authService = require("../../../services/authService");

exports.login = async (req, res, next) => {
    const { email, password } = req.body;
    console.log("login req body is ", req.body);
    //simple checker for username and password
    if (!email || !password) {
        return res.status(400).json({ message: "email or password is missing" });
    }

    try {
        //get the data from our auth service
        const { user, validPassword, token,  maxAge } = await authService.loginUser(email, password)
        //check if the user exists
        if (!user) {
            return res.status(401).json({
                message: "Login not successful",
                error: "User not found",
            });
        }
        //return error if the password is incorrect
        if (!validPassword) {
            return res.status(401).json({
                message: "Login not successful",
                error: "Password is incorrect",
            });
        }
        res.cookie("email", user.email, {
            httpOnly: true,
            maxAge: maxAge * 1000, // convert 2h to ms; maxAge uses milliseconds
          });

          res.cookie("userId", user._id,{
            httpOnly: true,
            maxAge: maxAge * 1000, // convert 2h to ms; maxAge uses milliseconds
          });
          
        //send our cookie with the token
        res.cookie("jwt", token, {
            httpOnly: true,
            maxAge: maxAge * 1000, //convert 2h to ms; maxAge uses miliseconds

        });

        //if everything is good return the user
        return res.status(200).json({
            message: "Login successful",
            user,
            
        });
       

    } catch (err) {
        res.status(401).json({
            message: "Login not successful",
            error: err.message,
        });
    }
};
```

verifyAccessToken:

```
const jwt = require("jsonwebtoken");
require("dotenv").config();

//this only works if you use cookie-parser
const checkCookie = (req) => {
    console.log('inside checkCookie')
    console.log('all our cookies are: ', req.cookies)
    //we get the jwt cookie we need
    return req.cookies['jwt']
}

//middleware for verifying the JWT
const verifyAccessToken = (req, res, next) => {
    //define token
    let token;

    //authenticate through Bearer token
    if (req.headers.authorization && req.headers.authorization.startsWith("Bearer ")) {
        token = req.headers.authorization.split(' ')[1]
        //logs so you see what's happening
        console.log('auth bearer token')
        console.log({ token })
    }
    else {
        token = req.headers["x-access-token"] || checkCookie(req) || null
        //logs
        console.log('our token is from x-access-token header, a cookie or null')
        console.log({ token })
    }

    //if we can't get our token anywhere then the response is an error
    if (!token) {
        return res.status(403).send("A token is required for authentication");
    }
    try {
        //we use the JWT library to verify the token
        //and we need to know the token_key which we encrypted our information
        const decoded = jwt.verify(token, process.env.TOKEN_KEY);
        //log
        console.log({ decoded })
        //the middleware adds the user information to the request and sends it to the route
        req.user = decoded;
    } catch (err) {
        return res.status(401).send("Invalid Token");
    }
    //if you have doubts check Express middleware docs: http://expressjs.com/en/guide/using-middleware.html
    return next();
};

module.exports = verifyAccessToken;
```

getSpecialization:

```
const {Specialization} = require('../../../models/specialization')


exports.getSpecialization = async (req, res) => {
    try {
      const specializzazioni = await Specialization.find({}, { _id: 0, __v: 0 }); // Escludi _id e __v dalla risposta
      res.json(specializzazioni);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Errore durante il recupero delle specializzazioni:', error);
      res.status(500).json({ message: 'Errore durante il recupero delle specializzazioni' });
    }
  };
```

routes

```
router.route("/login").post(login);


//router.use(verifyAccessToken);
router.use(verifyAccessToken);
router.route("/book").post(book);
router.route("/getbooking/:id").get(getBooking);
router.route("/logout").get(logout);
router.route("/getSpecialization").get(getSpecialization);
```

Flutter
Login APIService

```
static Future<bool> login(LoginRequestModel model) async {
    Map<String, String> requestHeaders = {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    };

    var url = Uri.http(Config.apiUrl, Config.loginAPI);

    var response = await client.post(url,
        headers: requestHeaders,
        body: jsonEncode(model.toJson())
    );

    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      // Settare i dettagli del login
      await SharedService.setLoginDetails(loginResponseJson(response.body));

      // Ottenere il valore del cookie 'set-cookie' dalla risposta
      String? setCookie = response.headers['set-cookie'];

      if (setCookie != null) {
        // Estrarre il valore del token dal cookie
        String? token = parseCookieValue(setCookie);
        print (token);

        if (token != null) {
          SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
          await prefs.setString('jwt', token);
        }
      }
      await getSpecializations();
      return true;
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  }
```

getSpecialization

```
static Future<List<Specialization>> getSpecializations() async {
    var url = Uri.http(Config.apiUrl, Config.getSpecializaionAPI);

    var response = await client.get(url);

    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      // Converte la risposta JSON in una lista di oggetti Specialization
      List<dynamic> jsonList = jsonDecode(response.body);
      List<Specialization> specializations = jsonList
          .map((item) => Specialization(
        specId: item['specId'],
        description: item['description'],
      ))
          .toList();

      return specializations;
    } else {
      return []; // o gestisci l'errore in base alle tue esigenze
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

NOTE 1:

***Fetching data and store it in the cache with flutter***

- with this one , just store your access token in a local db (i.e. sqflite, sembast etc.) or shared prefs and that access token should be included in your *"client"* instance whenever you make any request such as GET or POST.

example:

```
  Map<String, String> requestHeaders = {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'Authorization': 'Bearer $token',
  };

  var response = await client.get(url, headers: requestHeaders);
```

NOTE 2:

***I have then a middleware verifyAccessToken that checks if the token is available from the cookie***

- this is the one that's returning the error. *"A token is required for authentication"* the latter should resolve your issue.

NOTE 3:

***Refreshing the access token***

- the access token might have an expiration so make sure to use a refresh token mechanism before making any request again. In this case we can use dio plugin.

example:

```
var payload = {
          'grant_type': 'refresh_token',
          'refresh_token': REFRESH_TOKEN,
          'client_id': CLIENT_ID,
          'client_secret': CLIENT_SECRET,
        };
    
      
          var response = await dio.post(url,
              data: payload,
              options: Options(contentType: Headers.formUrlEncodedContentType));
```

Comment: Hi johnnydevv thanks for your help. I have modified the code by adding the header to the getSpecialization method :                              

    `Map<String, String> requestHeaders = {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      'Authorization': 'jwt $token',
    };
   ` there is no token in the responseHeader of the getSpecialization API. The verifyAccessToken retrives the token from the cookies created during the login process.

Comment: I think you mixed up the 'Authorization' key value pair.   Try using 'Bearer $token' as the value Instead of using 'jwt $token' .  This example format from this answer might help https://stackoverflow.com/a/41471788/8198554